# ViewState Management in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, postback, viewstate

i was recently surfing the msdn for the session state management tools, i came accross viewstate, which can be used the retain the page or controls value accross the page postback, so i created a simple application, which contains a `asp:textbox` and `asp:button` now i made the `EnableViewState="false"` for textbox and run the page, entered some values and clicked on the button, the page postbacked but the value was retained, i thought that would be because the pages viewstate property is enabled, so i changed the `EnableViewState="false"` in the page directives, and run the page, still the textbox value was retained in the textbox accross the postback, can anyone tell me with small example how the does viewstate work in my scenario

Comment: Can we see snippets of your markup and code?

Answer (score 0):

The `TextBox` is rendered as input control, **so the value is post back and set again** to the `TextBox`.

The viewstate have a meaning on the TextBox for the other attributes that you can set it pro grammatically, or in case that you make it hidden and you like to keep the content of it.